# Subquery inside IF as a value for a column with null value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery

Given:

```
t1{id,type}
t2{type,table1_id}
```

I'm using this:

```
SELECT IF(t1.type IS NULL, 'some default', t1.type) as ret from t1
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT IF(
    t1.type IS NULL, 
    IF(
        (SELECT t2.type FROM t2 WHERE t2.table1_id=t1.id LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL,
        table2.type,
        'some defaults'
    ),
    t1.type
) as ret from table1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This --

```
SELECT IF(
    t1.type IS NULL, 
    IF(
        (SELECT t2.type FROM t2 
           WHERE t2.table1_id=t1.id LIMIT 1)
           IS NOT NULL,
        t2.type,
        'some defaults'),
    t1.type
) as ret from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

seems to [work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d7b5/1).

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

> `IFNULL(expr1,expr2)`
>
> If `expr1` is not `NULL`, `IFNULL()` returns `expr1`; otherwise it returns `expr2`. `IFNULL()` returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Which would transfer your  current statement into:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.type, 'some default') AS ret FROM t1
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) block.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT CASE
        WHEN t1.type IS NULL
            THEN 'some default'
        ELSE t1.type
    END AS ret) AS subq
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. tried to reply before but some addon gave me troubles.  Anyway: i can see that it works, but my original question refers to the return value, how can i use a returned value from a subquery in the IF function?